# How to convert multiline file into a string in bash with newline character?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I convert a file with multiple lines to a string with `\n` characters in bash?

For example - I have a certificate that I need to configure in my configuration `JSON` file
so instead of having

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCMIIDB
MIIDBjCCMIIDB
    .... 
MIIDBjCCMIIDB==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I will have

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\n....\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Read the file line by line and append the read data to a variable

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I admit my example is not accurate. the ellipsis represents the content in between the line before that and the line after that. seems to me like the question is clear enough as I did not get bad feedabck.

Comment: your expected output shows your needs but `How can I convert a file with multiple lines to a string with \n characters in bash? ` line shows a different thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1=$1' ORS='\\n' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\n....\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
```

Comment: If this appears to not work, double check your file's line endings. You can assert the line endings are unix-friendly by by first running the file through `dos2unix`. 
A oneliner solution looks like: `cat file | dos2unix |  awk '$1=$1' ORS='\\n' /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash (with Bash≥4) possibility that should be rather efficient:

```
mapfile -t lines_ary < file
printf -v cert '%s\\n' "${lines_ary[@]}"
```

Check that it works:

```
echo "$cert"
```

One thing to note is that you will have a trailing `\n`. If that's not a concern, you're good with this method. Otherwise, you may get rid of it by adding the following line just after the `printf -v` statement:

```
cert=${cert%\\n}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash has simple string substitution.

```
cert=$(cat file)
echo "${cert//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

I originally had `'\n'` in single quotes in the substitution part, but I took them out based on testing on Bash 3.2.39(1) (yeah, that's kinda old).

Comment: this is what i needed! just a correction... it should be \\n and not \n. else it wont work.. so it becomes ===> echo "${cert//$'\n'/\\n}"

Comment: @Macindows Works both ways for me, but I added a second backslash based on your feedback. I'm still on Bash 3.2.57(1) here (stock macOS Catalina). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution,

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(/\n+/, "\\n")}1' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\n    .... \nMIIDBjCCMIIDB==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Through sed,

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\nMIIDBjCCMIIDB\n    .... \nMIIDBjCCMIIDB==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```