# How to take a multiline input in bash with newlines using Python code

Tags: python, bash, ssl

I am trying to automate the way we order SSL certificates on the command line using Python. But I am seeing issues with how to format a user multiline input. How can I make bash wait till the input is complete AND get the multiline input in a single line output?

For ordering certificates, we generate a CSR which is of this format

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICrjCCAZYCAQAwaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkx
fjfawcwkefmFNaWamsdffjawfbjwnfkwmelfmw[wefkwaeifbhwfmamfawfoawfj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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I take this as user input and you can see the way it's formatted, it uses newline every time. However, since bash considers a newline a command it gives me errors. 
My problem is more or less similar to this one: [How to convert multiline file into a string in bash with newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451551/how-to-convert-multiline-file-into-a-string-in-bash-with-newline-character)

Tried a while loop which looks something like this:

```
csr = ""
c = input("Enter CSR:")

while True:
    if "\n" in c:
        csr += c
        csr.replace("\n", "")
    break
```

But doesn't work as stated.

The expected result is something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----MIICrjCCAZYCAQAwaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkxfjfawcwkefmFNaWamsdffjawfbjwnfkwmelfmw[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------END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

But the moment I put in the CSR as input in Terminal, it errors out like this:

```
$ MIICrjCCAZYCAQAwaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkx
bash: MIICrjCCAZYCAQAwaTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgMCk5ldyBKZXJzZXkx: command not found
$ ETAPBgNVBAcMCFJvc2VsYW5kMREwDwYDVQQKDAhBRFAsIExMQzEfMB0GA1UEAwwW
bash: ETAPBgNVBAcMCFJvc2VsYW5kMREwDwYDVQQKDAhBRFAsIExMQzEfMB0GA1UEAwwW: command not found
$ cmVjcnVpdGluZy1pYXQuYWRwLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCC
bash: cmVjcnVpdGluZy1pYXQuYWRwLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCC: command not found
```

Can someone please tell me a way to take a multiline input in bash and then just put the key in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-from-stdin-into-a-variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/377943/how-do-i-read-multiple-lines-from-stdin-into-a-variable)

You can read multiple lines using a bash command like

```
myVar=$(</dev/stdin)
```

And you need to input Ctrl + D at the end to close the input stream.

If you are looking for python code, you probably need to include the input-statement into a loop.
Something like this:

```
print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    contents.append(line)
```